# Notation of memory in netlist?

Tags: verilog

One of my memory model files showing the notation IN22_R2P_W00064B080M02C064.mdt. I want to know what is W , B, M, C in the model name can any one explain ?

Comment: what are you talking about?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the Verilog language. Likely something tool/product  specific. Refer to your manual or update your question stating to tool/product you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Greg stated above, this is usually a naming convention to explain features (such as BIST, port widths/operations, etc.) and it most often is associated with process nodes (28nm, 14nmfinfet). Depends on what generated this model.

`R2P` would likely mean `2 port register file`

`W00064` likely means `64 bits` in width.

and so on. But this just looks like a pure model and not something that will eventually be used for synthesis.

TSMC has a memory "compiler" that will generate these models and will usually name them something strange like this but makes sense once you read the manual on it.